# Webpack. Pass parameters to entry point

Tags: javascript, webpack-2

I have a multi-page app. And I have configured multi-entry points with one js file. The reason for making this: these two pages have a lot of the same code.
So far, I have already read about webpack-plugins and webpack configuration without any result.

*Question:* Can I pass some parameter to **page1 entry point** and **page2 entry point** in order to my **index.js** file will resolve what exactly it should do? Is it possible? And could anyone give advice on this issue?

```
...
entry: {
    page1: "./index.js",
    page2: "./index.js"
},
...
```

Comment: Hi @young-b, what do you mean with passing parameters?

Comment: Thanks for reply, @ toomuchdesign. I mean pass some global variables for page1 entry and page2 entry.
It shoul be something like enviriopment variables. 
I have one entry point  - index.js
And i add it to each page. And inedex.js use specific logic depend on page.

Comment: Hi, i'm looking for the same feature, would be convenient for creating different builds based for example on a langage for translation purposes.

Answer (score 1):

`webpack-hot-middleware/client` uses a magic `__resourceQuery` for the job:

`if (__resourceQuery) {
  var querystring = require('querystring');
  var overrides = querystring.parse(__resourceQuery.slice(1));
  setOverrides(overrides);
}`

Here, `overrides` gets the querystring as an object.

Source: https://github.com/glenjamin/webpack-hot-middleware/blob/8984fa2845da68b8b9652669f738d6d49ce8e4b5/client.js#L16-L20

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to create an entry point for each page and require `index.js` from there.

Cleaner and easily readable.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have already done that. And I'm finding alternatives.(This solution will give superfluous files.)